# Real world applications of first order logic

Tags: artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

I study an AI course and we done some lectures about first order logic and the first thing that I was thinking is, what are the real world applications of first order logic and generally logical languages , especially in AI ?

Comment: Because of the ubiquitous presence of first order logic, I would say most if not all large enough software especially in artificial intelligence will be using it explicitly or implicitly, just like logic is used almost everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a specific example, [IBM Watson](https://www.cs.nmsu.edu/ALP/2011/03/natural-language-processing-with-prolog-in-the-ibm-watson-system/) should qualify. Check the links for details on how they use Prolog. I'd say that Prolog made a huge hype in its day, and most real today's system are based on different principles rather than "first-order logic programming" in narrow sense. However, there is definitely a niche for this approach. We live in the age of other hypes, that's it.